# Is it a bad practice to create a form on the fly from a controller in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I'm doing this from a controller:

```
$scope.logout = function()
  {
    var logout_form = document.createElement("form");
    logout_form.setAttribute("method","post");
    logout_form.setAttribute("action","logout");
    document.body.appendChild(logout_form); 
    logout_form.submit();
  }
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: you should really do all DOM stuff in a directive.

Comment: Yup, write directive(s) and/or use ng-switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to send a post request from the controller or a service you should use $http like

```
 $http.post("logout").success(function(res){}).error(function(errRes){});
```

If you need to do any DOM manipulation (add or remove HTML elements or otherwise access their attributes) you should use a directive like

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).directive("logoutForm",function(){
  return {
    restrict:"C",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      //Do DOM manipulation here
    }
  }
});
```

and in html use like

```
<div class="logout-form"></div>
```